# How to Disable control of Youtube with Keyboard Media Keys

Tags: keyboard, youtube

Recently Chrome / Youtube implemented the possibility to control Youtube content by using Keyboard media buttons, and i was wondering if it was possible to Disable that ? as i can't control Spotify over it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

1. Load `chrome://flags/#hardware-media-key-handling` in the Chrome address bar; this should open the right flag when loaded.
2. Set the Hardware Media Key Handling flag to Disabled.
3. Restart Google Chrome.

[Source: ghacks.net](https://www.ghacks.net/2019/04/17/fix-chrome-blocking-keyboard-multimedia-keys-from-working/)

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution need to go diable options in chrome flags : https://www.ghacks.net/2019/04/17/fix-chrome-blocking-keyboard-multimedia-keys-from-working/

Answer (score 0):

In addition to NekoTiki answer, if you looking for a temporary solution in order to use the media keys, you may launch the 3rd party app as Administrator (while chrome isn't)